# local .htaccess rewriterule works, but not on rackspace

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rackspace-cloud

My htaccess on the local works just fine, but when I push to my remote rackspace it doesnt work. I have tried looking up info about rackspaces special config on this area, but nothing is really coming up.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/([^\.]+)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/([^\.]+)
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ $1.php/$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions on what I can do or why rackspace wont accept it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is the rewrite module loaded? If not, it needs to be turned on
- Is the allow override for the directory that your htaccess file is in set to `All` or at least `FileInfo`? If not, then your server config needs to be setup so that your htaccess file is allowed to override server config settings.
- Have you checked your error logs? If something "doesn't work", and is generating an error, your apache server error logs will tell you why.